# how to do loop in Batch?

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, dos

I want to create something like this

```
dup.bat infile outfile times
```

example usage would be

```
dup.bat a.txt a5.txt 5
```

at it would create file a5.txt that has the content of a.txt repeated 5 times

however I do not know how to do for loop in batch, how to do it?

Comment: I am a little unsure of what you are trying to accomplish. Just get the contents of a.txt and paste it 5 times into a5.txt? If so I think it would be more appropriate to use PowerShell and the Get-Content call. For reference though a loop in batch is simply for. http://ss64.com/nt/for.html

Comment: @Mike Soule batch are mor universal and I do know it can be done using it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do the loop like this:

```
SET infile=%1
SET outfile=%2
SET times=%3

FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,%times%) DO (
    REM do what you need here
    ECHO %infile%
    ECHO %outfile%
)
```

Then to take the input file and repeat it, you could use `MORE` with redirection to append the contents of the input file to the output file.  Note this assumes these are text files.

```
@ECHO off
SET infile=%1
SET outfile=%2
SET times=%3

IF EXIST %outfile% DEL %outfile%
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,%times%) DO (
    MORE %infile% >> %outfile%
)
```

Answer (score 3):

For command line args

```
set input=%1
set output=%2
set times=%3
```

To do a simple for loop, read in from the `input` file, and write to the `output` file:

```
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,%times%) DO (
    FOR /F %%j IN (%input%) DO (
        @echo %%j >> %output%
    )      
)
```

Instead of taking in an output file, you could also do it via command line:

```
dup.bat a.txt 5 > a5.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

*sigh*

Compact Design:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET times=5
:Beginning
IF %times% NEQ 0 (TYPE a.txt>>a5.txt & SET /a times=%times%-1 & GOTO Beginning) ELSE ( ENDLOCAL & set times= & GOTO:eof)
```

Easy Reading:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET times=5
:Beginning
IF %times% NEQ 0 (
TYPE a.txt>>a5.txt
SET /a times=%times%-1
GOTO Beginning
) ELSE (
ENDLOCAL
set times=
GOTO:eof
)
```

Set your counter (times=5)
Start subroutine Beginning
If your counter doesn't equal 0, read a.txt and APPEND its contents to a5.txt, then decrement your counter by 1.  This will repeat five times until your counter equals 0, then it will cleanup your variable and end the script.
SET ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION is important to increment variables within loops.