# call in BATCH doesnt work

Tags: windows, batch-file, call, dos

I have created file called a.bat

```
call echo. > outfile
call dup.bat file1 outfile 7
call MORE file2 >> outfile
call dup.bat file1 outfile 10
```

when I execute it the output is

```
C:\>a
C:\>call echo.  1>outfile
C:\>call dup.bat file1 outfile 7
C:\>
```

I don't understand why it stops the excution after executing the first batch

the batch is an answer to this question
[how to do loop in Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598955/how-to-do-loop-in-batch)

the dup.bat

```
@ECHO off
SET infile=%1
SET outfile=%2
SET times=%3

rem IF EXIST %outfile% DEL %outfile%
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,%times%) DO (
    call MORE %infile% >> %outfile%
)
```

Maybe some silent exception is being thrown? how to catch it?

Any ideas?

Comment: The code you put there does not do any form of looping. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: You should give us the code of `dup.bat` as well ...

Comment: @Khez I tried to create one big batch from a lot of small ones, I have attached the source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it just works: execution does not stop, only echo stops!

Please check your output file `outfile` and verify its contents. The reason that you do not see the last two lines of a.bat is that dup.bat turns echo off…

Comment: you are right, i could have sword it did not work, but maybe there was some other bug. thx a lot :D